# eLisp call-process dvisvgm

Tags: unix, emacs, latex, pipe, elisp

I am trying to process a latex fragment to an SVG file, using dvisvgm. This works fine from the command line but fails when run from within elisp:

```
(call-process "dvisvgm" nil nil nil
            "--libgs=/usr/local/bin/gs"
            svgfile
            dvifile)
```

Can anyone tell me what I've missed?

Thanks!
-Adam

Comment: What is the error message?  Have you checked the paths and environment being used?

Answer (score 1):

Try to simply use `M-! dvisvgm --libgs=/usr/local/bin/gs <svgfile> <dvifile>` instead, if it works and you still want to write it in elisp, you can use simpler API: `shell-command`, for example:

```lisp
(shell-command
 (format "dvisvgm --libgs=/usr/local/bin/gs %s %s"
         (shell-quote-argument svgfile)
         (shell-quote-argument dvifile)))
```

If `dvisvgm` takes time and you don't want it to block you Emacs, add `&` to that shell command or use `start-process` etc to create an asynchronous process. For example, use `start-process`:

```lisp
(start-process "foo-dvisvgm" nil "dvisvgm"
               "--libgs=/usr/local/bin/gs"
               svgfile
               dvifile)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. How would you do this using start-process?

Comment: @Adam I've updated my answer for it, but to learn how to use `start-process` you'd better read info manual instead: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html